# Is it possible to customise the Docusign Iframe and avoid signers to have to enter their information?

Tags: iframe, docusignapi

Recently I have been looking into some different API for signing documents online, what I am looking for is one that has a customisable Iframe to avoid breaking the already established style of our website.

I would have wanted to know if Docusign proposes this kind of service.

For example, if we would just have the pdf file and a spot to sign, that would be perfect.

I hope I was clear enough with my question, thanks for your possible answers.

EDIT: I would have also liked to know if there is a way for the signer to not have to enter his personal information/sign in. One where that information is entered by us when the procedure is created.

Is it also possible to change the size of the zone where the signer signs, I was some other signing API's proposed it, but haven't seen it on Docusign.

How can I also change the language of the Iframe and disable the automatic mobile version.

Thanks for spending the time reading and helping me with these questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Docusign Iframe isn't 100% customisable, but you can remove some little extra UI with `&noDownloadPrint=true&appname=docusignit`, or add `&disable_cc_for_selfsign=true` to remove the "Sign and Return". From the creation of the Docusign EnvelopeAPI, you can't change the language of the Iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe for the signing when you use "embedded signing" in your integration. This is a common scenario and the signer won't have to log-in.
Even when using an email, most people just click on a link and they don't need to log in to DocuSign in order to sign.

Comment: This has only partly answered my question that is in the title of this post. I would have liked to know if the Docusign Iframe was customisable.

Comment: customisable in what way? what do you want to change exactly?

Comment: In my question I say _For example, if we would just have the pdf file and a spot to sign, that would be perfect._ I'd like to know if we are able to modify the iframe to avoid all excess information like the popups, the menu at the top et the buttons to leave a message. So that our signer just has the pdf file with a spot to sign on it.
I would also like if possible an answer to the two last questions in my initial post.
Thanks

Comment: About the language, I'd like first time signers to access the Iframe already in the right language and not the have to change it.

Comment: you can control the lang if you use embedded signing. You cannot customize everything in the signing UI. You can avoid the request to "sign and return" (if that's the pop-up you mean) as well as the one for adopting a signature.

Comment: Could you be so kind as to link me to the spot in the Docusign Documentation where it is explained `how to control the lang`, `avoid the request to "sign and return"` and  `avoid the one for adopting a signature`. I have had a thorough read through of it but haven't seen these. Thanks

Comment: Lang - look at https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/ for the EmailNotification Object

Comment: add this to the url you get to remove some of the extra UI - "&noDownloadPrint=true&appname=docusignit"

Comment: add this to the url "&disable_cc_for_selfsign=true" to avoid the "sign and return"

Comment: Thank you very much for the help you've given me, one last question : Is there a place in the Docusign Documentation, where the extra URL params you gave me are written ?

Comment: I don't think so. Please mark this question as answered if you don't mind Louis.

Comment: @InbarGazit Can you please tell me how you were able to find those? I am trying to hide the back and the edit recipient buttons.